# Accessing the layers of a multidimensional array and performing some function on each layers

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

I have this code

```
A = unidrnd(2,100,30)-1;
B = reshape(A, 100, 3, 10);
```

B is a multidimensional array with 10 layers of 100x3 Matrices. Now I want to perform this code,

```
C = length(nonzeros(all(B,2)))/100;
```

where the function on the right hand side of the code is suppose to generate 10 values corresponding to the result of the 10 layers, but all I get is a single value. The right hand of the code checks how many  rows are all 1's. It takes the number of rows that are all 1's and divides it by 100 to obtain  the **fraction** of the number of rows that are all 1's.

How can I obtain the result of every `100 x 3` layers of the 3D matrix using the single line of code I have shown above such that I do not have to use a loop? The result **C** had to be array of the results as expected.

Comment: Please carefully read the tag description of [code-review](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-review), it clearly says **DO NOT USE THIS TAG TO ASK FOR A CODE REVIEW OF YOUR CODE**, you've got to use http://codereview.stackexchange.com for that. If you do not want a review, but got a concrete question (which I think you do) please remove that tag.

Comment: @Adriaan Thanks for the information. I have removed that tag.

Comment: In the future, please actually read the tag descriptions of the tags you consider for use. It'll a save you a few closed questions

Comment: You forgot to tell us **what you want** to perform at each layer.  All you have said is *"...where my aim is to store in `C` the values corresponding to each of the 10 `100 x 3` layers...."*.  **WHAT** do you want to store?  We can't tell you whether you're doing that operation right because we don't know what it is you want.

Comment: In plain English, describe what the right hand side of the code is doing for the statement involving the assignment to `C`. Even with your edit, the description is nonsense.

Comment: @rayryeng sorry for not having clarity on the question. I hope the edits help now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You started out well. `all(B,2)` is good, it gives you the `100x1x10` matrix that's `1` where the corresponding rows are all 1's and `0` otherwise.

`nonzeros`, however, simply lists all of the nonzero elements of the entire matrix, in your case, a string of 1's, completely disregarding the dimensions of the array. You'd get the same results with `nonzeros(A(:))` as with `nonzeros(A)`.
[Note: `nnz(A)` would get you the same results as `length(nonzeros(A))`, but that's not what we want to do anyway.]

Since your matrix is binary (the output of `all` is a logical array), we can count the number of non-zero elements by summing the matrix elements. And `sum` gives us a dimension argument just like `all`, so we just sum the *columns* that `all` gave us.

```
C = sum(all(B,2),1)/100;
```

This gives you a `1x1x10` array of percentages. If you wanted that to just be a normal vector, you could use `squeeze`.

```
C = squeeze(sum(all(B,2),1)/100);
```

Comment: I tried comparing the value of the first layer using your code and my code, but they do not seem to generate the same result.  
**My code**
`C = length(nonzeros(all(B(:,:,1),2)))/100;`
ans:  0.0900  

**Your code:**
`D = sum(any(B(:,:,1),2),1)/100;`
ans: 0.8600

Comment: It works only if we replace the function `any` by `all` in the code you suggested

Comment: @nashynash You're right. My brain went on vacation on that one. I had it right in the description, though! I'll edit the code :)

Comment: Alright. Do that and I will accept it as the answer.

Comment: You still need to update the text where you have mentioned about `any`

Comment: @nashynash Okay, I did a search this time :) should be all fixed

Comment: @nashynash you can always propose an edit yourself. You don't have to wait for beaker.